# dynamic_cast succussful in an unexpected manner

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-cast

I was playing with `dynamic_cast` to understand its usage and came up with the code provided below. I used to believe `dynamic_cast<D*>(B*)` succeeds if and only if:

- `B` is a polymorphic type i.e. it has a virtual function AND
- `D` is derived from `B`

But in the code below `Base` and `NonDerived` classes are not related in above fashion still the `dynamic_cast<NonDerived*>(Base*)` succeeds. I was expecting it to fail and return a `NULL` instead. Which C++ rule is kicking in here?

I'm using a C++11 conformant compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived: public Base {
    public:
        void DerivedFun(){
            std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
        }
};

class NonDerived{
    public:
        void NonDerivedFun(){
            std::cout << "NonDerived" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    Base *pb = new Derived();

    Derived *pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pb); // Expected this to succeed and it did
    pd->DerivedFun(); // Prints "Derived" as expected

    NonDerived *pn = dynamic_cast<NonDerived*>(pb); // Expected it to fail but it succeeded?
    pn->NonDerivedFun(); // Prints "NonDerived", expected this to throw some null pointer exception!!

    delete pb;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check whether `pn` was null or not? You'll have undefined behavior if it is.

Comment: `pn->NonDerivedFun()` is successful and printing "NonDerived". I find it strange!!!

Comment: Undefined behavior is, well, undefined. Anything can happen.

Comment: Before calling `pn-NonDerivedFun();` put in `if (!pn) throw "null pointer exception";` and you're golden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> pn->NonDerivedFun(); // Prints "NonDerived", expected this to throw some null pointer exception!!

There is no such thing as a "null pointer exception" when dereferencing a null pointer. It's [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) to do so. To avoid it in this case, you must check if the `dynamic_cast` succeeded or not:

```
if (pn != nullptr) {
    pn->NonDerivedFun();
}
```

Comment: So my understanding of `dynamic_cast` is correct but I don't fully understand 'null pointer' and its behavior?

Comment: @MasterJEET I'd say you don't fully  understand undefined behavior (commonly abbreviated as "UB"). Yes, `dynamic_cast` returns null just as you expected. But dereferencing a null pointer results in UB.

Comment: @MasterJEET Correct.  In your code snippet [`pn` is null](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f9beb0d1a3259df).  The behavior of your program when calling `pn->NonDerivedFun()` is therefore undefined.  Anything at all can happen.  In this case, the call "works", likely because `NonDerived::NonDerivedFun` doesn't read or write any data from the object it's called on, but that behavior is not guaranteed and may be different from compiler to compiler or program to program.